# Got Sql Error in Syntax and need efficient sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

As per my requirement i made the below query. Now it not working.
Query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   T_INV_DTL T
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT inv_dtl_id,
                       Employee_id AS emp_id,
                       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Employee_id) AS Employee_id
                FROM   T_INV_INVESTIGATOR
                GROUP BY
                       inv_dtl_id
            )TII
            ON  T.inv_dtl_id = TII.inv_dtl_id
       JOIN T_INVESTIGATION TI
            ON  T.inv_id = TI.inv_id
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT inv_dtl_id
                FROM   T_INV_BILL
                GROUP BY
                       inv_dtl_id
            )TIB
            ON  T.inv_dtl_id = TIB.inv_dtl_id
       JOIN T_Insurance_company TIC
            ON  TI.client_id = TIC.ins_cmp_id
WHERE  1 T.Report_dt != '0000-00-00'
       AND (
               T.inv_dtl_id NOT IN (SELECT inv_dtl_id
                                    FROM   T_INV_BILL TIBS
                                    WHERE  TIBS.inv_dtl_id NOT IN (SELECT 
                                                                          inv_dtl_id
                                                                   FROM   
                                                                          T_INV_BILL
                                                                   WHERE  
                                                                          Bill_submitted_dt = 
                                                                          '0000-00-00'))
           )
ORDER BY
       Allotment_dt DESC 
       LIMIT 20
```

Can anyone tells the problem and can you please modify to more efficient query(Suppose if we have more than 100 records, then we take the count for it for pagination it should be give faster).

T_INV_DTL is main table and it connect to others. So my probelm is each entry of this table T_INV_DTL has multtiple investigation bill in the table T_INV_BILL. Report_dt in the T_INV_DTL. So my outcome is that i need result if there’s a report date in T_INV_DTL  and not atleast one bill date in T_INV_BILL.

I need the result with both if there’s a report date in T_INV_DTL  and not atleast one bill date in T_INV_BILL(If all have entered the bill submitted date it does not need it).

Comment: It's very hard to "debug" your query without having the table's structure. You can "create" a demo in [*sql fiddle*] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6328d/1) and send us a link. Otherwise, you should run each and every inner query and make sure it returns the expected result and take it from there.

Comment: `WHERE 1 T.Report_dt !=  '0000-00-00'`  should be: `WHERE T.Report_dt !=  '0000-00-00'`

Comment: What does "Now it not working" mean? If you don't take the time to actually describe the problem, it's very difficult to help you solve it. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, and "it not working" is meaningless to everyone but you.

Comment: @KenWhite take it easy brother :) even though you're right, let him enjoy the benefit of the doubt, since he's new in the neighborhood!

Comment: Am new to this and also i don't how to handle the sqlfiddle.. Any way i copy my table structure to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587e7 I hope u get this and help me

Comment: @alfasin: Thanks for your input. However, if no one points out the problem with the question, how will he learn to not make the same mistake in the future? And without knowing what "not working" means, how can we answer? I don't have the data to run the query to find out what's wrong. Do you? If not, a description of what "not working" means is pretty important. :-) If you don't agree, try calling your doctor and saying "My body not working. What's wrong and how do I fix it?" and see if that works for you.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @KenWhite I started by saying that you're right :) the only thing I was aiming towards was the harsh tone, but maybe it was just in my mind - sorry if that was the case.

Comment: I added the conditions above.

Comment: @user1852645: You **still** have not explained what "it not working" means. **Please do so if you want help**. Once again, **we can't read your mind**. "It not working" means nothing to anyone but you unless you explain to us what it means.

Comment: Plz look at once more... Condion is need to show record if there’s a report date in T_INV_DTL and not atleast one bill date in T_INV_BILL(If all have entered the bill submitted date it does not need it).

Answer (score 0):

While I admittedly don't know what issues you're having (please provide addl info), your query does look like it could be optimized.

Removing your Where criteria and adding to your Join should save 2 of your table scans:

```
SELECT *
FROM   T_INV_DTL T
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT inv_dtl_id,
                       Employee_id AS emp_id,
                       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Employee_id) AS Employee_id
                FROM   T_INV_INVESTIGATOR
                GROUP BY
                       inv_dtl_id
            )TII
            ON  T.inv_dtl_id = TII.inv_dtl_id
       JOIN T_INVESTIGATION TI
            ON  T.inv_id = TI.inv_id
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT inv_dtl_id
                FROM   T_INV_BILL
                WHERE Bill_submitted_dt != '0000-00-00'
                GROUP BY inv_dtl_id
            )TIB
            ON  T.inv_dtl_id = TIB.inv_dtl_id
       JOIN T_Insurance_company TIC
            ON  TI.client_id = TIC.ins_cmp_id
WHERE  T.Report_dt != '0000-00-00' 
    AND TIB.inv_dtl_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
       Allotment_dt DESC 
       LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I need the result with both if there’s a report date in T_INV_DTL and not atleast one bill date in T_INV_BILL(If all have entered the bill submitted date it does not need it).